# If an homomorphism maps elements of the same orders to each other, is then an isomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

I know that, given $f:G_1 \rightarrow G_2$ homomorphism, if $g \in G_1$ has order $n$, then $f(g)$ has order that divides $n$, and that if $f$ is an isomorphism then $f(g)$ has order equals to $n$.

Now my question is, if $f$ is an homomorphism such that $\text{ord}(g)=\text{ord}(f(g))$ for every $g \in G$, can we say that $f$ is an isomorphism?

Comment: No, this is not so.  It is easy to find counterexamples, say, using $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$.

Comment: So the statement is true only if we add the hypothesis of $f$ being a surjective homomorphism?

Comment: A counterexample is $f:{\mathbb Z} \to {\mathbb Z}$ with $f(g)=2g$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that an element has order $1$ if and only if it is the identity. If you have a homomorphism that respects orders, then if $g\in G_1$, $g\neq e$, it follows that $f(g)\neq e$. Thus, $f$ has trivial kernel, and hence is one-to-one.

In particular, if $G_1$ and $G_2$ are finite of the same order (size), then $f$ must be a bijection. In that case, it is an isomorphism. In even more particular, if $G=G_1=G_2$ and it is a finite group, then $f$ will be an automorphism/isomorphism from $G$ to itself.

If $G_1$ and $G_2$ have different orders, then you must have $|G_1|\lt |G_2|$; this is certainly possible and $f$ need not be an isomorphism. For example, the map from $C_2$ (cyclic of order two) to $C_2\times C_2$ sending $x$ to $(x,e)$ respects order but is not an isomorphism, because it is not surjective.

For infinite groups, it is also not the case that $f$ needs to be an isomorphism, even if they have the same cardinality: $f\colon\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$ given by $f(x)=2x$ respect order but is not surjective. If you want one in which elements have finite order, just take a direct product of infinitely many copies of $C_2$, and then let $f$ be the “right shift” morphism.

Comment: Why in the world was this downvoted???

Comment: @Randall: Good question...